# Search for a subarray in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of Objects:

```
arrObj : [{ id: 0, text: 'At', start: '15.000' },
      { id: 1, text: 'the', start: '15.492'},
      { id: 2, text: 'left', start: '15.984'},
      { id: 3, text: 'we', start: '16.476' },
      { id: 4, text: 'can', start: '16.967'},
      { id: 5, text: 'see...', start: '17.459' },
      { id: 6, text: 'At', start: '18.166'},
      { id: 7, text: 'the', start: '18.440' }]
```

I have to search for an array and return the start and end word ids. For example in this case:

```
["At", "the"]
```

I have to return [(0,1),(6,7)]
I am currently using a for each loop to iterate over the arrObj and see if the words match. I also tried indexOf by joining the objects texts but it returns the char index not array index.

But this does not seem efficient. How can i efficiently search for something like this?

Comment: Still vague. Explain more!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Look into [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if you're targeting recent browsers.

Comment: We need to know what you want for output at the very least to help you.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to dedupe objects with the same values for `text`.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: The efficient way to do this is called "Boyer-Moore".

Comment: @Brad *I have to search for an array and return the start and end word ids.* - no, I think it's just a subsequence search, which is basically analogous to finding substrings in a larger string.

Comment: If you go to the link, I pointed to Array.prototype.indexOf, not String.prototype.indexOf, which baao has answered with. It would be nice if you could include the code you've tried so that we don't duplicate your work...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan my answer uses Array.prototype.indexOf() ...

Comment: @baao Apologies, that sentence didn't come out like I wanted it to, and it's too late to fix.

Comment: Ahh, I think now I get what you wanted to say.. :-) @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce to get the start and end positions in an array:

```js
let arrObj = [{ id: 0, text: 'At', start: '15.000' },
      { id: 1, text: 'the', start: '15.492'},
      { id: 2, text: 'left', start: '15.984'},
      { id: 3, text: 'we', start: '16.476' },
      { id: 4, text: 'can', start: '16.967'},
      { id: 5, text: 'see...', start: '17.459' },
      { id: 6, text: 'At', start: '18.166'},
      { id: 7, text: 'the', start: '18.440' }];

let arr = ["At", "the"];
let res = arrObj.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  let index = arr.indexOf(b.text);
  if (index === 0) {
    a.push(i);
  } else if (index === 1) {
    a.push([a.pop()].concat(i));
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Note that this will only work if the array with the searchterms holds 2 entries.

If you need more than two searchterms in the array, this will work:

```js
let arrObj = [{ id: 0, text: 'At', start: '15.000' },
      { id: 1, text: 'the', start: '15.492'},
      { id: 2, text: 'left', start: '15.984'},
      { id: 3, text: 'we', start: '16.476' },
      { id: 4, text: 'can', start: '16.967'},
      { id: 5, text: 'see...', start: '17.459' },
      { id: 6, text: 'At', start: '18.166'},
      { id: 7, text: 'the', start: '18.440' }]

let arr = ["At", "the", "left"];
let res = arrObj.reduce((a,b,i) => {
 let index = arr.indexOf(b.text);
  if (index > -1) {
  if (index % arr.length === 0) {
   a.push(i);
  } else {
   let tmp = a.pop();
    a.push(tmp instanceof Array ? tmp.concat(i) : [tmp].concat(i));
  }  
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output of the second Snippet be `[[0,1,2]]` instead of `[[0,1,2],[6,7]]`?

Comment: I don't think so, it seems like it solves what OP was after. It's not specified if a partial match should be excluded, and the second snippet is just there for completion, I guess the first is better suited to the question. @RickHitchcock

Answer (score 1):

A solution for any length of a search array. It stores the index of the search array and increments with a match.

It adds only an array with the indices, if the indices for all items of the search array are found.

```js
var array = [{ id: 0, text: 'At', start: '15.000' }, { id: 1, text: 'the', start: '15.492' }, { id: 2, text: 'left', start: '15.984' }, { id: 3, text: 'we', start: '16.476' }, { id: 4, text: 'can', start: '16.967' }, { id: 5, text: 'see...', start: '17.459' }, { id: 6, text: 'At', start: '18.166' }, { id: 7, text: 'the', start: '18.440' }],
    search = ["At", "the"],
    result = array.reduce(function (i, t) {
        return function (r, a, j) {
            if (search[i] === a.text) {
                t.push(j);
                i++;
                if (i === search.length) {
                    r.push(t);
                    t = [];
                    i = 0;
                };
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(0, []), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```